# How to fix "index out of bounds" error when reloading TableView after Realm Database filtering?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Realm database with many objects and am trying to implement filtering functionality. I also have a TableView that uses the Realm results as a datasource.  When the TableView initially loads with all objects everything works fine, but then when I filter the results and try reloading the TableView I get this error: 'Index 4 is out of bounds (must be less than 3)'.

I thought this would be an easy fix, but I've gotten completely stuck. I made sure that the numberOfRowsInSection function was using my realm results.count and I've made sure that the filtering functionality is working correctly as well.  When I print out the filtered list it appears in the debug console with the correct objects and correct number of objects.

```
var schools: Results<School>?
var sortedSchools: Results<School>?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(sortedSchools!)
        return sortedSchools?.count ?? 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fullListCell", for: indexPath) as! FullListCell

        let schoolIdentifier = sortedSchools?[indexPath.row].identifier

        cell.schoolName.text = sortedSchools?[schoolIdentifier!].name

        return cell
    }

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category CONTAINS %@", categoryChosen)

sortedSchools = schools?.filter(predicate)
print(sortedSchools!)
allSchoolsTableView.reloadData()
```

I currently have 10 objects in the sortedSchools results and when a button gets pressed the results get filtered using an NSPredicate and only 3 schools remain.  In the debug console these 3 schools do actually get printed out, but when the TableView reloads it gets the 'index out of bounds' error.  I don't understand this because there is now only 3 objects in the datasource the TableView is reading from and it even prints 3 from the print statement within the numberOfRowsInSections function.  Why is it even looking for an index 4 value?  I thought this was  a timing issue and maybe the realm results just hadn't been updated by the time the table went to reload, but I've tried delaying the reload for testing purposes and that hasn't seemed to change anything either.

Comment: Do you have a schoolIdentifier of 4? `sortedSchools?[schoolIdentifier!].name`?

Comment: Yes I have school identifiers 1 through 10

Comment: I was pointing to your problem. You need to use `cell.schoolName.text = sortedSchools?[indexPath.row].name`.

Comment: Ah I can't believe I missed something that simple.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Happens to us all.